# What's the "!" symbol after ViewDataDictionary instance in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I created a new Web Application using Visual Studio 2015 RTM and choose MVC template for it.

it created me a bunch of code there including a controller named `AccountController` containing a method exactly like this:

```
<AllowAnonymous>
Public Function Login(returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
    ViewData!ReturnUrl = returnUrl
    Return View()
End Function
```

What the **`!`** symbol does there? is it a part of vb.net syntax?

Comment: The ! operator in VB.net is used to call the "default property". This can only be use when the default property accepts one string parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the exclamation point operator. See section "Exclamation Point (!) Operator" in [Special Characters in Code (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx):

> Use the `!` operator only on a class or interface as a dictionary access operator. The class or interface must have a default property that accepts a single `String` argument. The identifier immediately following the `!` operator becomes the argument value passed to the default property as a string.

So, instead of doing:

```
ViewData("ReturnUrl") = returnUrl
```

You can do:

```
ViewData!ReturnUrl = returnUrl
```